# TDD demos/guides/videos including fake repositories or domain models

Tags: tdd, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I have to rewrite an old application and I would like to start using the repository pattern for data access and also write as many tests as possible for the required functionalities.

Can you recommend some videos/guides with more complex examples of TDD including fake repositories or domain models (preferably starting from scratch)?

Comment: I like that even though you asked the question, and received no answers, you still went out and shared your research.

Comment: @jamiebarrow: just to be able to point others to this answers. Up to a certain point SO can be viewed as a blog with a very very good uptime.

Comment: @Robert: you're welcome. Please upvote for the link that helped you the most, or just add a comment to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Full Stack, Part 3: Building a Repository using TDD](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack/The-Full-Stack-Part-3-Building-a-Repository-using-TDD)

Answer (score 2):

[Eliminate Database Dependencies in Test-Driven Development](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/09/01/Eliminate-Database-Dependencies-in-Test-Driven-Development.aspx) ([printable version](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/09/01/Eliminate-Database-Dependencies-in-Test-Driven-Development.aspx?p=1)) from [Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com).

Answer (score 1):

[The Repository Pattern](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) from [The NHibernate FAQ](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/) blog.

Answer (score 1):

[TDD Kata for DDD (building a simple domain model)](http://codingsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/07/tdd-kata-for-ddd-building-simple-domain.html) from [C# Development and TDD](http://codingsolutions.blogspot.com)  blog.

Answer (score 1):

The sample chapter [Preparing for Infrastructure](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/0321268202.pdf) from [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Applying-DomainDriven-Design-and-Patterns-With-Examples-in-C-and-NET/9780321268204.page)